# Why is Breq confident that Lieutenant Skaaiat will not recognize her?

Tags: imperial-radch, ancillary-justice

On her arrival at Omaugh Palace, Breq says

> It was impossible that Lieutenant Skaaiat would recognize me

which also appears to be true of Daos Ceit (the former flower-bearer). That makes sense if the segments of *Justice of Toren* One Esk that Skaaiat and Daos encountered in Ors did not include — or at least did not often include — One Esk Nineteen; but it's not clear to me that that's the case.

What segments of *Justice of Toren* One Esk were Lieutenant Skaaiat and Daos Ceit familiar with in Ors? If they include one Esk Nineteen, why is Breq so sure he will not be recognized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Imperial Radch Wiki](https://imperial-radch.fandom.com/wiki/Skaaiat_Awer):

> Lieutenant Skaiaat Awer was the commander of **Justice of Ente** Seven Issa during the Shis'urna annexation

From [the Breq page](https://imperial-radch.fandom.com/wiki/Breq) on the same wiki:

> It is lightly implied that the body that Breq inhabits now is the one that was attached to her ship's consciousness in Ancillary Justice **after** action on Shis'Urna

(Emphasis mine.)

The annexation of Shis'Urna and the events surrounding it were the catalyst for the destruction of *Justice of Toren*, and One Esk Nineteen was one of the last (or maybe the last) ancillary added to *Justice of Toren*'s complement.  Since Lieutenant Skaiaat wouldn't have been on board *Justice of Toren* after the annexation, it's likely that Lieutenant Skaiaat never crossed paths with One Esk Nineteen.

Comment: Oh wait — One Esk Nineteen is the body we see being attached to replace the body killed on Shis'Urna? That would explain it!